# jquery datepicker conflicts with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

So I have an angular application and I want to insert [this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) jquery datepicker.
I know there are angular datepickers outhere but my manager wants this  jquery datepicker.

The jquery datepicker does not work. I just include the external files for the jquery datepicker and add it to `div`. I get `datepicker is not a function`. It jams my application.

I use angular 1.5.0 and bootstrap 3.3.6.

Is there a way to bypass this conflict?

Thanks

This is my structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <base href="/apps/ely/">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

        <link href="./css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">        
        <link href="./css/timelineCSS.css" rel="stylesheet">        

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/angular-filter.min.js"></script> 

        <!--  <script src="./js/ui-bootstrap-1.2.2.min.js"></script> -->                    

        <script src="./js/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>                   

        <script src="./js/progressbar.min.js"></script>    

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link href="./css/cssStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./css/cssStyleQueries.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>         
            var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angular.filter']);                   
            app.config(function ($routeProvider , $httpProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {
```

and later in my code, inside the controller of the page I have

```
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

and my html is just

```
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Well if it says that datepicker is not a function. Then it sounds more like you are not initiating it correctly rather than a conflict. Could you try to make a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your setup? Then it is way easier to help.

Comment: this link will help you [codepen](http://codepen.io/tutorialab/pen/JDxkn)

Comment: here's a **working** copy [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TTBhwCqioKEELAGfkrwl?p=preview)

Comment: @KristianBarrett I updated my original post. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: we don't see any element with id `datepicker`

Comment: @sharmask This is interesting. Can you give more info on that, how does it work?  I just add this `directive` to my code? Thanks

Comment: Yes...you just wanna add `directive` code in your `app.js` and call like this `<input type="text" datepicker />`

Comment: @sharmask OK. What externl libraries, relate to jquery-ui do I have to import? Because now I get `elem.datepicker is not a function`.

Comment: yes you want to include externl libraries .. just click js setting icon in codepen that will show you..`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`,`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js`

Comment: @sharmask Thanks, I just solve this, check my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

try like this... add externl libraries above the angular script

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("datepicker", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var updateModel = function (dateText) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
        });
      };
      var options = {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
          updateModel(dateText);
        }
      };
      elem.datepicker(options);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper" ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="datepicker"  datepicker />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look mom , no conflict

Here is what I did

structure of external libraries

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <base href="/apps/elety/">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

        <link href="./css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">        
        <link href="./css/timelineCSS.css" rel="stylesheet">        

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/angular-filter.min.js"></script> 

        <script src="./js/ui-bootstrap-1.2.2.min.js"></script> 

          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


        <script src="./js/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>                   

        <script src="./js/progressbar.min.js"></script>    

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link href="./css/cssStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./css/cssStyleQueries.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>





        <script>         
            var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angular.filter']);                   
            app.config(function ($routeProvider , $httpProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {
```

and then in my angular (javascript)

just copy the directive

```
app.directive("datepicker", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var updateModel = function (dateText) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
        });
      };
      var options = {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
          updateModel(dateText);
        }
      };
      elem.datepicker(options);
    }
  }
});
```

and then in my html , just

```
<input type="text" ng-model="datePicker" datepicker />
```

Thanks everyone